# How can I create link to the json-view of an object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

What do I need to change in the code below to make it link to a view rendered as json?

```
<%= link_to 'JSON Link', @mymodel %>
```

So I'd like to generate the following url

```
http://localhost:3000/mymodels/1.json
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:3000/mymodels/1
```

(These urls both work as expected.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you must specify the format:

```
<%= link_to 'JSON Link', your_model_path(@mymodel, :format => 'json') %>
```

The URL helper methods can be retrieved by running:

```
rake routes
```

The first column is the name of the helper method, on which you should append either `_path` or `_url`, the latter will generate an absolute URL.

More information is in the [Guide To Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: So simple and yet I didn't find this anywhere. Thanks!